# MacOS quick action or service automator in context menu NOT quick actions context sub-menu

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur, automator, macos-monterey

I've created an automator "quick action" job, that's the only way that I know I can add a custom menu line when I right click on files or folders. This script work only with pdf files and launch a bash script.
Everything works but I'm going nuts because I don't want my custom menu line to be in quick actions ( big Sur / Monterey ) sub-menu but directly available as I right-click. I've done this no problem until Big Sur come out.

Anyone know a way or what am I doing wrong ?

Best Regards,
Simo

[image]

Comment: You might want to try asking in [apple.se].

Comment: This isn't a programming question.